# Mono C#: Unexpected Symbol

Tags: c#, mono, csc

So this is my first question on StackExchange. I'm a Programmer who uses many Programming Languages, so I'm a bit ashamed that I'm missing what could be happening here. I'm using Mono on Xubuntu 18.04, and whenever I try and compile the Code below, it throws back a bunch of errors about Variables I declared, and the else keyword. I followed along with a C# tutorial on YouTube, and it's driving me crazy trying to figure out where the error(s) are. Here's the code, which I edited a bit to personal taste:

```
using System;

class A_Better_Way

{
  static void Main(string[] args)

  {
    Console.Write("Enter a number:");

    double num_one = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); //Doubles allow the use of decimals

    Console.Write("Enter \"+\", \"-\", \"/\" or \"*\":");

    string operator = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.Write("Enter another one:");

    double num_two = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    if(operator == "+" ) //If Statements: Easy as magic. Easy as Jiff.

    {
      Console.WriteLine(num_one + num_two);

    }

    else if(operator == "-")

    {
      Console.WriteLine(num_one - num_two);

    }

    else if(operator == "/")

    {
      Console.WriteLine(num_one / num_two);

    }

    else if(operator == "*")

    {
      Console.WriteLine(num_one * num_two);

    }

    else

    {
      Console.WriteLine("You fail at life.");

    }

    Console.ReadLine();

  }

}
```

Any help would be most appreciated. And, I'm glad to be here.

Comment: `operator` is a reserved word. Rename that variable name to something else.

Comment: I decided to use the @ symbol as pointed out below. I appreciate your reply. :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

`operator` is a keyword in C#, so you cannot use it as variable name.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/operator

For a future, please specify error messages you got. It will help others to understand your problem and give an accurate answer.

Comment: If you really need to use a reserved keyword as a variable name, you can prefix it with `@`. So here, `@operator`.

Comment: @spender, thank you, I did not know about this possibility. But there's can be needed very rarely, as my mind.

Comment: ...can be useful when (for instance) dealing with JSON that has prop names that are reserved keywords.

Comment: Thank you @Miamy! I really appreciate it! I'll be sure to keep the suggestion in mind!

Comment: And the other comments were helpful also. Thanks guys!